# Using sqlite db created in Windows but to be accessed in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I already have a sqlite3 db file that I created in Windows, is there a way to package this file into my android application and access it as a sqlite db from within the application or do I have to create a db on application load or something in Android only?

The db has about a thousand records, so writing sql scripts again might be monotonous and cumbersome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got this [link](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/), seems to serve my purpose

Answer (score 2):

Package it as an asset or raw resource. Copy it out from there onto the appropriate spot on the device. Downside: You will take up 1.5x to 2x the space on the flash (for the possibly-compressed copy stored in the APK plus the actual to-be-used copy).

Or, download the database from a server on first run.